# Move element when the mouse leaves the original container jQuery UI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to move the draggable elements only when the mouse leaves the original container. While the mouse is still inside the original container, the elements is draggable while it remains still. When the user's mouse leaves the original container while is dragging, then start to move the draggable element.

Here is what I have done so far

```
$('.photo-segment').draggable({
        containment:'#layout-draggable',
        scroll:false,
        revert:"invalid",
        opacity:0.8,
        zIndex:100,
        helper:function(event){
             return $( "<div></div>" ); //make it look like the element is not moving at the beginning or the mouse is still inside the container.
        },
        start:function(event, ui){
            initial_rect = $(this).parents('.photo-segment-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect(); //specify the region the of the container, when the mouse is inside this region, don't move the element at all, when the mouse is outside of this region, start moving, the container is the same size of the draggable element.
        },
        drag:function(event,ui){
            if(initial_rect.left < mouseViewPortX && mouseViewPortX < initial_rect.right && initial_rect.top < mouseViewPortY && mouseViewPortY < initial_rect.bottom){
                //don't move the element at all, using the default helper that make the element look like static
                console.log('inside');
            }else{  
                //when the cursor move out of the original container, make the helper becomes original and allow moving
                console.log('outside');
                $(this).draggable( "option", "helper", "original" );
            }
        }
    });
```

This approach is not ideal. Once the mouse start exiting the container, the code will set the helper back to the original, however, this won't move the element right away. I have to start a new dragging then the element is able to move. What I need is once the current dragging make the mouse outside of the given region, make the container move right away. I'm not sure whether this is possible. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle of your code